# Cost for Google speech-to-text?

Tags: price, google-cloud-speech

I am trying to understand when Google will charge for what they call "premium" and when the "standard" costs apply. The main info is here, but it is not very clear:

> Pricing  |  Cloud Speech-to-Text Documentation  |  Google Cloud
>   https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/pricing?hl=uk

Does anyone know where there is more specific information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the API references page, we find that there is a flag for declaring that you wish to use premium models see:

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/RecognitionConfig

This implies that your application controls which model is used and hence which pricing applies.

Comment: Nice catch, thanks! A bit surprising too. Wonder how it works?

Comment: This is a pure guess ... I'm imagining that Google has trained models to recognize speech data.  As speech is processed, the obvious end goal is to return the textual content.  There is a logical "cost" to recognize the content in terms of CPU execution and the time needed to perform that processing.  I'm assuming that the standard processing gives a quality of response that is sufficient for many cases but if one needs a higher quality, the time/cost increases and Google has to pass that on to the user.

Comment: Yes, that is my guess too. And that they are struggling with matching a simple cost model to their actual costs (so they can safely keep prices low).